# ADD a new column with specific values: SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm on SQL Server.
I try to add a new column to a table with specifique values in each row.

I have a Table like that:

| loc_1 | loc_2 |
| --- | --- |
| [0.5,1.0] | [0.5,1.0] |
| [1.0,1.0] | [0.5,1.0] |

The expected result is:

| loc_1 | loc_2 | dist |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [0.5,1.0] | [0.5,1.0] | 0.0 |
| [1.0,1.0] | [0.5,1.0] | 0.5 |

The only help i find on internet is when i want to add a new column with a default value. But it's not what i try to do here.

I would like to do something like that:

```sql
ALTER TABLE myTable 
ADD dist VARCHAR(200) 
values (0.0, 0.5);
```

Comment: That statement you have doesn't make sense. You are adding a single column, yet expecting the column's value to have 2 values? A column only contains **one** scalar value, not many. Also, your `loc_1` and `loc_2` column look denormalised; assuming they are X and Y coordinates, you should really be storing them in separate columns: `Loc1_x` and `Loc1_y`, for example.

Comment: @Ouakrat . . . Or if this is geo data you might want to look into the Spatial data functionality in SQL Server (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/spatial-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: I know i can't do that. i'm lookinf for the way to add this values to my table with out drop this one and create the same table with this new column and specifique values. Actually, i'm computing some values in Python and now i want to add this new column with these values.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, thanks, i look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to know the distance between the `loc_1` and `loc_2` using the formula we all had to learn in middle school.

You will need to change the schema for this to function well. What we see right now is ***wrong***, because it tries to put two values in the same column and because it requires you to use a text type like varchar to store numeric data. Instead, you need something more like this:

| Loc1_X | Loc1_Y | Loc2_X | Loc2_Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.5 | 1.0 | 0.5 | 1.0 |
| 1.0 | 1.0 | 0.5 | 1.0 |

This not only splits apart the each value into it's own field, but also lets you store them in a numeric format you can use to do math, instead of text.

Given that table, with separated numeric fields, you can add a **[Computed Column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver15)** to apply the distance formula like this:

```sql
ALTER TABLE [MyTable] ADD [Dist] as (  
    SQRT( ((Loc1_X - Loc2_X) * (Loc1_X - Loc2_X)) + ((Loc1_Y - Loc2_Y) * (Loc1_Y - Loc2_Y)) )  
)
```

Comment: Nice! this is worked very well for me! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to do in multiple steps:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD dist VARCHAR(200); 
UPDATE TABLE myTable SET dist = 0.0 WHERE loc_1 = '[0.5,1.0]';
UPDATE TABLE myTable SET dist = 0.5 WHERE loc_1 = '[1.0,1.0]';
```

Answer (score 0):

T-SQL does not support that, you'll need to split your command in multiple parts.

- First use `ALTER` to add the `dist` column. You can specify a default value for all rows, but not different values for each row, and no formula either.
- Then use `UPDATE` to set `dist` in each row to what it should be.

A remark: `dist` looks **numeric** in value, so you should use a [numeric datatype](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/numeric-types?view=sql-server-ver15), and definitely not a VARCHAR type.
The same also applies to `loc_1` and `loc_2`, but then splitted. It would make a lot more sense to split these into `loc_1_x`, `loc_1_y`, `loc_2_x` and `loc_2_y`, all of a numeric type such as `FLOAT`.

Full example code (with loc_1 and loc_2 still as VARCHARs):

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (loc_1 VARCHAR(20), loc_2 VARCHAR(20))
GO
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES('[0.5,1.0]', '[1.0,1.0]'), ('[0.5,1.0]', '[0.5,1.0]')
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CalcDist(@loc_1 VARCHAR(20), @loc_2 VARCHAR(20))
RETURNS FLOAT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN 123.45 -- Do your calculation here, which would be a HUGE LOT easier
                  -- if each @loc_ parameter was split into @loc_..._x and @loc_..._y
END
GO

ALTER TABLE myTable ADD dist FLOAT DEFAULT(-1)       -- Change the table
GO
UPDATE myTable SET dist = dbo.CalcDist(loc_1, loc_2) -- Update the rows
GO

SELECT * FROM MyTable
```

Comment: Thanks! this is really helpfull!  Can we do that with out function but with a column already computed?  Actually, i have the dist already computed in a list (with python) and i juste want to add this column already computed into the SQL Server by.

Comment: Sorry, I know nothing about how Python, or how it connects with a database. But in general to update rows based on other values in the same rows, the most efficient way is to do it all in the database, instead of first retrieving all data rows, then computing on them, and then sending all updated rows back to the database.